# A clarification of MERGE best practices

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, best-practices, merge

I just wanted to ask a clarification about something on the MSDN from the "[Optimizing MERGE Statement Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)" page.

I am working with a data warehouse that takes in records from many different databases and stores the data. All of the tables in my warehouse database basically follow this same pattern:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    database_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    ,FooPk BIGINT
    ,Bar NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Qix NCHAR(10)
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        database_guid ASC
        ,FooPk ASC
        )
    )
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [iv].[LoadSomeTable] 
    @databaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    MERGE Foo
    USING #FooStaging AS Source
    ON Foo.FooPk = Source.FooPk AND Foo.database_guid = @databaseGUID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET Bar = Source.Bar
                  ,Qix = Source.Qix
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (database_guid, FooPk, Bar, Qix)
            VALUES (@databaseGUID, FooPk, Bar, Qix);
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #FooStaging (
    FooPk BIGINT
    ,Bar NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Qix NCHAR(10)
    )

--Data gets loaded in to #FooStaging from a C# call to SqlBulkCopy then calls iv.LoadSomeTable
```

The thing I am now concerned about is I just read this statement from that MSDN page

> Specify only search conditions in the ON `<merge_search_condition>`
>   clause that determine the criteria for matching data in the source and
>   target tables. That is, specify only columns from the target table
>   that are compared to the corresponding columns of the source table. Do
>   not include comparisons to other values such as a constant.

After reading that I am thinking I did my query wrong and my merge statement should be

```
MERGE Foo
USING #FooStaging AS Source
ON Foo.FooPk = Source.FooPk
WHEN MATCHED AND Foo.database_guid = @databaseGUID THEN
    UPDATE SET Bar = Source.Bar
              ,Qix = Source.Qix
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (database_guid, FooPk, Bar, Qix)
        VALUES (@databaseGUID, FooPk, Bar, Qix);
```

But that does not "feel" right to me because the `database_guid` field is part of the primary key so shouldn't it be included with the `on`? If I had it in the `WHEN MATCHED` and I upload one database with a `FooPk` of `1` then I upload a second database with a `FooPk` and a different `@databaseGUID` I am not sure if `NOT MATCHED` will fire or not (Just tested, it does not).

Which way is the correct way to use MERGE?

Comment: Well, probably the best practice is to [not use `MERGE` at all](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) - and not just to get out of this jam, where the "right" thing to do doesn't line up with the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would venture that your best approach is to use separate statements for each of the potential actions, and put them in a serializable transaction. You get to use tried and true statements with no funny semantics or "best practices" violations, and you get to avoid all of the problems I outline in this post, including wrong results bugs and potential index corruption:

- [MERGE with Caution](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: Do you have any postings on the way to do a "proper" UPSERT with discrete statements instead of using MERGE? I am still relatively new to professional level sql development.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1106934/579117) answer.