# Merge Failed when update same rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, merge

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

I know this error can be fixed with update and not exists statements.

But i need this to be done with merge since merge will be faster than two statements.

**Source:**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| Productid | Imagetype |     Imagename     | Website | Thumb90 | Thumb200 | Thumb500 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   3144000 | small     | 3144000_small.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       0 |        1 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       0 |        0 |        1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

**Target:**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| Productid | Imagetype |     Imagename     | Website | Thumb90 | Thumb200 | Thumb500 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   3144000 | small     | 3144000_small.jpg | Google  |       0 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144000 | medium    | 3144000_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144000 | large     | 3144000_large.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | small     | 3144005_small.jpg | Google  |       0 |        1 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       0 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | large     | 3144005_large.jpg | Google  |       0 |        0 |        1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

**Merge:**

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
| Productid | Imagetype |     Imagename     | Website | Thumb90 | Thumb200 | Thumb500 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|   3144000 | small     | 3144000_small.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144000 | medium    | 3144000_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144000 | large     | 3144000_large.jpg | Google  |       1 |        0 |        0 |
|   3144005 | small     | 3144005_small.jpg | Google  |       0 |        1 |        0 |
|   3144005 | medium    | 3144005_medium.jpg| Google  |       1 |        1 |        1 |
|   3144005 | large     | 3144005_large.jpg | Google  |       0 |        0 |        1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

**Query:**

```
MERGE INTO [luannw2016].[ImageThumbnailTrack] AS TARGET
USING #ImageThumbnailTrack AS SOURCE ON TARGET.ProductId = SOURCE.ProductId
AND TARGET.ImageType = SOURCE.ImageType
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE
    SET ImageName  = SOURCE.ImageName,
        Website    = SOURCE.Website,
        Thumb90    = SOURCE.Thumb90,
        Thumb200   = SOURCE.Thumb200,
        Thumb500   = SOURCE.Thumb500
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT ([ProductId],[ImageType],ImageName,Website,Thumb90,Thumb200,Thumb500)
    VALUES ([ProductId],[ImageType],ImageName,Website,Thumb90,Thumb200,Thumb500);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is no secret that I am [not a fan of `MERGE`, for good reasons](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), and typically when I see customer code with `MERGE`, I re-write it using the "old" way of separate statements (and recommend others [do the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61186/a-clarification-of-merge-best-practices), especially when they are not `MERGE` experts).

> since merge will be faster than two statements.

**NO IT WON'T.** `MERGE` still runs the exact same semantics as separate statements would. There is [no performance advantage at all](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100945/1186). Please [read up on it](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) and be sure you understand how it works - if you are so confident `MERGE` is faster, then when you get your statement working, run some tests and try to prove it. I'm afraid you'll be disappointed with the results, but at least now your conclusion will be based on facts.

I think the error message is pretty clear; since `ProductId`,`ImageType` is not unique, you might need to add the `ThumbXX` columns to the comparison.

```
AND TARGET.Thumb90    = SOURCE.Thumb90
AND TARGET.Thumb200   = SOURCE.Thumb200
AND TARGET.Thumb500   = SOURCE.Thumb500
```

Also you should properly alias the `VALUES()` list:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT ([ProductId],[ImageType],...)
    VALUES (SOURCE.[ProductId],SOURCE.[ImageType],...);
```

I would still write this as `UPDATE ... WHERE EXISTS` and then `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` (and wrapped in an appropriate transaction of course, which your current `MERGE` statement needs but lacks).

Comment: Are you saying avoid merge in this situation ?

Comment: @Ragul Yes, that is my suggestion. But you should also make sure your UPDATE can identify a single row uniquely in the source table - an UPDATE won't complain about that, it will just perform the same work multiple times.